# How to make my table responsive , without media queries?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to save make a my table responsive, How can I do it ?

Comment: Provide some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Specify width, height, everything that is in pixel in % or em..

Comment: This is a rather general question but adding `width: 100%;` should make it responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make table responsive you have to use relative value instead of fixed value : The example below can explain more :

Responsive table

```
table { 
  width: 100%; /* Relative Value  */
      }
```

Non-Responsive Table

```
table { 
  width: 1200px; /* Fixed Value  */
      }
```